# trying to add a key/value pair to obj2 that i can access only thru obj2(add key/value pair which doesnt affect the object that it is referencing)

Tags: javascript

```js
let obj1 = {
    var: 1223,
}

let obj2 = obj1;
```

I can access the properties of obj1 from obj2

like(`obj2.var`)
but if I do something like this :
`obj2.name = 123;`
then the change will also be made in the object obj2 is referencing to that is `obj1`

& I want to add a key/value pair to `obj2` such that it does not change the key/value pair of the referenced `obj1`

Comment: You need to create a copy of obj1 when assigning it to obj2. read about shallow copy and deep copy

Comment: see https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/3-ways-to-copy-objects-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you need to perform a "deep copy". For example:

```
let obj1 = { var: 1223 };
let obj2 = {...obj1};
```

This way, changes you make on obj2 won't affect obj1.